# how execute a Python Script with activeresource?

Tags: python, activeresource

I need to execute this python script: http://superjared.com/static/code/googleMX.py

I installed pyactiveresource, but when I executed it: python googleMX.py I had this response.

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "googleMX.py", line 15, in ?
 from pyactiveresource import ActiveResource
 ImportError: cannot import name ActiveResource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by Responding myself...

It was using an older version of pyactiveresource. The author (Lucky) creates another one http://gist.github.com/330832